# Is lua called from redis interpretted or compiled?

Tags: compilation, lua, redis, interpretation

Redis supports lua scripting. Using eval command, we can execute a lua script in redis. Is the lua script compiled or interpretted when redis calls a lua script?

Comment: What do you believe the difference between those two would be in this case? What question are you really trying to ask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lua scripts sent to the Lua library for execution are always compiled to Lua VM instructions before execution. These instructions are then interpreted by the Lua VM.

Comment: Here http://intro2libsys.info/introduction-to-redis/lua-scripting it is written that redis has a lua interpreter. Does it mean that when redis makes a call to execute a lua script, it is interpretted and not compiled?

Comment: Redis wraps your script into a function and uses [`luaL_loadbuffer`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_loadbuffer) as you can see [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/902b877/src/scripting.c#L850-L865).

Comment: Good to know actually! And the compilation should be done only once as you send only SHA1 for next lua calls.